# Use Javascript / jQuery Replicate HTML Form POST with ISO-8859-1 charset

Tags: php, javascript, forms, post, character-encoding

My PHP web application is running on ISO-8859-1 encoding. When I post an HTML form with accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" to a PHP server, this is what I receive on server side

a. ASCII characters in their original form.

b. Special characters that can be represented in ISO-8859-1 in their original form.

c. Special characters that can not be represented in ISO-8859-1 converted to HTML entities.

All of the data is received as proper ISO-8859-1 encoded characters. I want to replicate the exact same behavior with JavaScript or jQuery. All the solutions I have tried end up sending all the special characters to PHP file as double encoded characters and I have to utf8_decode them.

I have made a working solution as follows:

a. convert unsupported special characters to HTML entities.

b. send JavaScript AJAX post request with XMLHttpRequest/ActiveXObject. To do that I have to 'encodeURIComponent()' the data.

c. receive the post data on server and 'utf8_decode()' it because 'encodeURIComponent()' encodes the special characters as UTF-8.

I want a JavaScript solution which makes sure that I receive proper ISO-8859-1 encoded data from POST on server side, so that I don't have to do 'utf8_decode()'. In other words, I want the JavaScript solution to exactly replicate the form behavior with accept-charset="ISO-8859-1".

Thank you

Comment: *My PHP web application is running on ISO-8859-1 encoding* — In the 21st century? Why?!

Comment: @Quentin Because it is not a 21st century app :). I'm a developer and it's owned by my client of course. The app is so vastly spread that migrating the code and especially the database with billions of records to UTF-8 is not the first option..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no sure-fire way in javascript to do this. Character encoding is not a forte of Javascript and I believe it is mainly because it leaves such areas to the discretion to others such as the HTML that describes the content, the Server Language which does the parsing or the Web Server that provides the environment.

As far as any URI encoding/decoding function in JS is concerned, it is all UTF-8 and that is inbuilt, as in, there is no param you can pass to override it.

You could also try something in the lines of overriding the MimeType and specifying a new one like:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
if (xhr.overrideMimeType) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType('application/x-javascript; charset=ISO-8859-1');
}
```

Not sure how stable it is, but it is one direction you might want to explore..

Comment: It doesn't change anything.. Thanks for your support though. At least now I'm not alone to say that it cant be done via JavaScript.